# Installing QGIS

Tags: qgis, installation, windows

I installed QGIS and I am having this message when I start qgis

```
Python error: Couldn't load plugin 'rastertool' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method See message log (Python Error) for more details."
```

Because of it I think I cannot make many processes when I use raster tools.
I have tried to fix it but I cannot.

Do you know how I can fix it??

I use QGIS for windows and I use QGIS 3.4.14 version "Medeira"

Below is the whole error.

```
Couldn't load plugin 'rastertool' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 335, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/Users/lambr/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\rastertool\__init__.py", line 35, in classFactory
    from .RasterTool import RasterTool
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 685, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/lambr/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\rastertool\RasterTool.py", line 51, in 
    from pandas import read_csv
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 685, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'


Python version: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.4.14-Madeira Madeira, c92881c294 

Python Path:
C:/Users/lambr/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\leastcostpath
C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python
C:/Users/lambr/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/lambr/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\gdal2\pymod3\scripts
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\gdal2\pymod3\lib\site-packages
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\Scripts
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\python37.zip
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\DLLs
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/lambr/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/lambr/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\aderyn
C:/Users/lambr/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\aderyn
```

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Maybe you could try the latest release version of QGIS (which is 3.10.1)? You can find it [here](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html). If you have the same problem with this version too, you can find information [here](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/bugreporting.html) on how to report a QGIS bug.

Comment: Johan, they're using the latest version of the LTS branch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At the beginning I downloaded the latest version but I had the same issue.

Comment: I edited my answer, can you try again with the new path. Make sure my path matches yours.

Answer (score 2):

> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'"

In order to solve your problem, you need to install the python module `pandas`. You can follow the following steps:

1. Find python.exe which is in your QGIS folder. (Example: `C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37`)
2. Opens a command prompt
3. Type the following command: `cd C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37 & python -m pip install pandas`

Tell me if the installation of the module is done correctly and if your problem is solved.

Comment: Hi Vincent, is shown in the question post that the path to Python is: `C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37` (it is an OSGeo4W install), so the third point of your answer will return an error.

Comment: Hi Gabriel, thanks for your remark, I edited my post with his path.